# How do I solve the Error Code -36?

Tags: time-machine, photos, photos.app, restore, library

I deleted some photos from iPhotos and Photos libraries that I should not have. I want to restore these from my Time Machine back of a couple days ago.
When I do this I keep getting the following error

```
The Finder can’t complete the operation because some data in “Photos Library” 
can’t be read or written.(Error code -36)
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Here's the official definition of that error code (word for word): "Mac OS error -36 (ioErr): I/O error (bummers)". It is indeed bummers, as Apple suggests. You may want to run a disk verify in Disk Utility.

Comment: I have done that on both the Mac hard drive and the Time Machine disk. Still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get these files from time machine by accessing the time machine from the terminal. I used the following commands

```
sudo tmutil listbackup
```

this listed all the backup directories, their names contain the date of the backup.
then

```
cd <to the backup I wanted>
```

then

```
cp -R <iPhotos backup folder> <Pictures folder>
```

during this command, I did get a warning for one of the image files. My guess is that `Finder` cannot handle this situation.